# Retrieving value of a variable in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have following scenario.

```
#!/bin/bash
export avalue_name="stack"
LOOPERS=${LOOPERS:-avalue}
for LOOPER in $(echo "$LOOPERS" | tr ',' "\n")
do
   actualVar="$LOOPER""_name"
   echo "actualVar - $actualVar"
done
```

Output is

```
actualVar - avalue_name
```

I want the output to be

```
actualVar - stack
```

How would I do it?

I tried `$($LOOPER_name)`. It doesn't work either.

Comment: Where do you declare `$LOOPER_name`? Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I updated the script in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two approaches:

---

Use an intermediate variable, and use shell indirect reference on that:

```
$ avalue_name="stack"

$ LOOPER=avalue

$ temp="${LOOPER}_name"

$ echo "${!temp}"
stack
```

---

Or use `eval`, **not recommended**:

```
$ eval echo "\$${LOOPER}_name"
stack
```

---

Points:

- `_` is a valid variable constituent character, so while referring a variable you need to enclose it with `{}` when another valid variable constituent character is immediately before or after it
- unless absolutely necessary, do not use all uppercases for user-defined variables to prevent possible mix-up with the environment variables